# How to move html data to struct in Golang

Tags: html, struct, go

I'm new to Golang and I am trying to move data from an action field to a struct.

My func main is:

```
func main () {
    http.HandleFunc("/public/", func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, r.URL.Path[1:]) })
    http.HandleFunc("/public/new_user/", signup) 
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}


// struct for recieving Signup data input from signup.html
type Signup struct {
    name  string
    email string
}

// func to receive data into struc above FROM signup.html
func signup(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var S Signup 

    S.name = r.FormValue("name")
    S.email = r.FormValue("email")

    //this is just to test the output
    fmt.Println("%v\n", S.name)
    fmt.Println("%v\n", S.email)
}
```

I have `http.HandleFunc("public/new_user/", signup)` which should render the `signup` function.  However, I am receiving a BLANK html page when I route to `public/new_user` instead of receiving the struct from func signup.

The `S.name = r.FormValue("name")` and `S.email = r.FormValue("email")` lines ABOVE are getting their info from the signup page which is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sign Up</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<br/>

<form action="/public/new_user" method="post" id="form1">

<label>Name:</label>
<input type="string" name="name" />
</br>
</br>
<label>Email:</label>
<input type="string" name="email" />
</form>

</br>

<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>

</body>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

As you can see, this page routes to `public/new_user` upon submit.  Can anyone please tell me why `public/new_user` is blank seeing as how I have `public/new_user` in:

```
http.HandleFunc("/public/new_user/", signup)
```

Which should render the signup function? Thanks

Comment: Look at using https://github.com/goji/param or http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/schema to marshal `r.PostForm` data into a struct. https://github.com/justinas/nosurf may also be useful for CSRF protection.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you registered your handler for the pattern `"/public/new_user/"` but you direct your form post to `/public/new_user`.

You have to change your HTML `<form>` to use this URL:

```
<form action="/public/new_user/" method="post" id="form1">
```

The importance of this is that even though visiting the URL `/public/new_user` works because an automatic redirect (`301 Moved permanently` response) happens, but the submitted form will not be "carried" over when your browser makes the 2nd request to the new URL (ending with a slash).

After doing this you will still receiving a blank page because your `signup()` function does not write any response (although you will now see the submitted and printed form data on your console).

If you want to see a response, either write something or redirect to another page.

Also note that [`fmt.Println()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println) does not have a format string parameter, it just prints everything you pass to it. Use [`fmt.Printf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf) if you want to use a format string. Also you can use the `%+v` format string to print a complete struct with field names.

For example:

```
func signup(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var S Signup
    S.name = r.FormValue("name")
    S.email = r.FormValue("email")

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", S)

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Form received, you used name: %s", S.name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are skipping form validation. You must check client input and you should put token parameter for prevent Xsrf attack.

You can use this package for validate user's inputs.

[Form validator](https://github.com/albrow/forms)